# If $f(x) = \frac{x}{x+1}$ and $g(x) = 2x-1$, find $(g\circ f) (x)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $f(x) = \frac{x}{x+1}$ and $g(x) = 2x-1$, find $(g\circ f)(x)$.

My answer is $\frac{x-1}{x+1}$. However, the answer key in the book states $\frac{2x}{x+1}$. How is that? Is the book wrong?

Comment: Don't trust answer keys in books. They're usually wrong.

Comment: Thanks really appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Yep, looks like the book forgot the $-1$.

Answer (score 4):

[Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B2x%7D%7Bx%2B1%7D-1) and me agree with you, if
$$f(x)=\frac{x}{x+1}, g(x)=2x-1 $$ then
$$g \circ f(x)=g(f(x))= 2f(x)-1 = \frac{2x}{x+1}-1= \frac{2x-x-1}{x+1}= \frac{x-1}{x+1}.$$